# How to make a query from 2 ranges when the layout are different?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [sheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zRqP_EqgoQCYaz2UBpoHeTY96f__sSharc6lP-v9hjo/edit?usp=sharing).

What I'm trying to do is make a query from 2 ranges, but the ranges have different layouts, in Sheet1 country is col M, and sheet2 country is col N.

So how you can make a query from 2 ranges when the layouts are different?

And I also want to add a column in the query result to have the sheet name to know from where comes the data.

I have a tab called query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY({{Sheet1!A2:K,Sheet1!K2:K,Sheet1!L2:Q};Sheet2!A2:R},
 "select Col13,count(Col15) 
  where Col13<>'' and not Col13 contains 'Otro' 
  group by Col13 order by count(Col15) desc 
  limit 17 label Col13 'Pais' ", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, thank you, that works perfect, but how can I add a column on the query to know from which sheets comes the info ?

Comment: like this: `={QUERY({Sheet1!A2:K,Sheet1!K2:K,Sheet1!L2:Q},
 "select Col13,count(Col15),'Sheet1' 
  where Col13<>'' and not Col13 contains 'Otro' 
  group by Col13 order by count(Col15) desc 
  limit 17 label Col13 'Pais','Sheet1''from sheet' ", 1);
  QUERY({Sheet2!A2:R},
 "select Col13,count(Col15),'Sheet2'
  where Col13<>'' and not Col13 contains 'Otro' 
  group by Col13 order by count(Col15) desc 
  limit 17 label count(Col15)'','Sheet2''' ", 0)}`